# Generating machine utilisation chart from time data over a 12 hour period

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I would like to generate a line plot which depicts the utilisation of a system of machines over a 12 hour period. As I am new to R I would like some advice on the approach I could use to generate such a plot.

Here is an example of the data frame that is used -

```
Machine StartTime StopTime
A       10:30     11:00
B       12:00     13:00
B       7:00      9:00
A       13:00     16:00
```

Say, the 12 hour period is from 4:00 to 16:00

My approach (probably not the most efficient) - is to create an empty matrix with 720 rows (1 for each minute), then check if the utilisiation of the system using the formula:

```
utilisiation = machines Busy / total machines
```

This would mean that I would some how need to iterate through each minute from 4:00 to 16:00. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but its not something out of the bag.  I'd probably use data frames or data tables instead of a matrix.  I'll use data.table in my examples.

To create a sequence of times you can try:

```
data.table(time=seq(from=as.POSIXlt("2016-06-09 4:00:00"),to=as.POSIXlt("2016-06-09 16:00:00"),by="min"))
```

However, this is probably unnecessary since the plots can recognize times.  (Well, at least ggplot2 can).  For instance

```
require(data.table)
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

#Make the data table.

dt<-data.table(Machine=c("A","B","B","A"),
               StartTime=c("10:30","12:00","7:00","13:00"),
               StopTime=c("11:00","13:00","9:00","16:00"))

#Reshape the data, so that we have one column of dates.

mdt<-melt(dt,id.vars = "Machine",value.name = "Time",variable.name = "Event")

#Make the time vector a time vector, not a character vector.

mdt[,time:=as.POSIXct(Time,format="%H:%M")]

#delete the character vector.

mdt[,Time:=NULL]

#order the data.table by time.    

mdt<-mdt[order(time)]

#Define how each time affects the cumulative number of machines.

mdt[Event=="StartTime",onoff:=1]
mdt[Event=="StopTime",onoff:=-1]

#EDIT: Sum the onoff effects at each point in time -this ensures you get one measurement for each time -eliminating the vertical line.

mdt<-mdt[,list(onoff=sum(onoff)),by=time]

#Calculate the cumulative number of machines on.

mdt[,TotUsage:=cumsum(onoff)]

#Plot the number of machines on at any given time.

ggplot(mdt,aes(x=time,y=TotUsage))+geom_step()
```

That will get you something like this (EDIT: without the vertical spike):

[image]

Comment: It's cool ! Your code is much better than mine. @dfj328 When you add `mdt <- mdt[!duplicated(mdt[,time], fromLast=T)]`, one time returns only one result.

Answer (score 1):

I made your idea the code. It checks every machine is on/off per minute.
[Caution] If your data is big, this code takes much time. This method is simple but not efficiency.

```
# make example data
d <- data.frame(Machine = c("A","B","B","A"),
                StartTime = strptime(c("10:30", "12:00", "7:00", "13:00"), "%H:%M", "GMT"),
                StopTime = strptime(c("11:00", "13:00", "9:00", "16:00"), "%H:%M", "GMT"))
# cut from 4:00 to 16:00 by the minute  
time <- seq(strptime(c("04:00"), "%H:%M", "GMT"), strptime("16:00", "%H:%M", "GMT"), 60)

# sum(logic test) returns number of True. Sapply checks it each time.
a <- sapply(1:721, function(x) sum((d$StartTime <= time[x]) & (time[x] < d$StopTime)) / length(levels(d$Machine)))
plot(time, a, type="l", ylab="utilisiation")
```

[image: plot]